# What does + in exponent mean?

Tags: functions

I am trying to solve a problem that at some point gives me this:

$$ f=C\cdot g^{+} $$

I am confused at to what that $+$ means. Does it indicate that g must be positive? Because that's the only time my calculations work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably $$x^+=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\ge0\\ 0&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

See [positive and negative part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts).

Comment: And for functions $f$ the notation is overloaded to $f^{+}$ to denote the positive part of $f$ taken pointwise. Concretely:
$$f^{+}(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if $f(x) \geq 0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $f(x) < 0$}\end{cases}$$